# Which is the proper way to add functionality to a control?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to add some properties and methods to a Panel control, to be used only once in my application. What will be more appropiate?

- Create a new Panel control class, derived from Panel, which will be
  instantiated only once.
- Create a static class which takes a standard Panel control as a
  property.

Or any other way (my knowledge of C# is still quite limited)?

Comment: can you please post some code what you have tried,

Comment: you can achieve easily with code behind

Comment: IMO, creating a custom control is really only worth the effort if you intend to reuse it in  several applications and it provides significant capabilities that do not exist in native controls.

Comment: In my first option I don't mean to create an user control, but simply adding a class derived from Panel in Form1.cs, with some extra properties and methods.

Comment: @Vicky, could you please detail how to achieve it with code behind?

Comment: @PauloBarretto, if you need to add some properties, than the only way is to create a new class - derived from Panel or wrapper for Panel. static class can have only static properties, and static Control property (instance) is not the best idea

Comment: @Ash, A wrapper would be a class taking my Panel control as a constructor argument, and adding properties to it?
That's exactly what I intended with the second option, but in a wrong way.

Comment: @PauloBarretto,  adding properties to it - yes, taking my Panel control as a constructor argument - not necessary: it can be constructor injection, or property injection